# Saving program execution state for fuzzing

Tags: dynamic-analysis, fuzzing, instrumentation

Suppose I have a program that has two functions, `functionA` and `functionB` called sequentially.

`functionA` requires a significant amount of processing in order to execute, and in the course of the execution sets up and maintains many global variables referenced by `functionB`.

I want to fuzz input to `functionB`, but having to run `functionA` first forces me to wait about 10 seconds before I can see the results of a particular test.

How can I save the program state after executing `functionA` and resume at `functionB` when I want to run a set of tests?

Additionally, what mechanisms are there to alter the program variables to reflect the new fuzzing values?

Comment: Intel PIN tool has an [API](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/58423/Pin/html/group__CONTEXT__API.html) to replay execution by saving/restoring the processor states, memory changes need to be tracked manually. Also have a look at this *[pdf](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~krste/papers/pin-wbia.pdf)*. However do note that the API has changed than what is mentioned in the pdf, but you will get the general idea.

Comment: As mentioned above, memory accesses can be tricky to follow, as well as things like open file descriptors, etc. If you are doing some in-memory fuzzing and those functions don't have a lot of side effects it is doable. Otherwise it gets really cumbersome very quickly.

Comment: Similar with the suggestions above, if the functionA does not have side effects (e.g. open/read/write into files, call system calls), then you can use Context Manipulation API of Intel Pin to write your fuzzer. I have implemented such a "reverse execution" mechanism for my personal project, you can see in (https://github.com/tathanhdinh/PathExplorer/blob/windows_version/version_1/src/base/checkpoint.cpp). I am sorry for the self-advertisement.

Answer (score 2):

[`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot) would help for creating a snapshot of program state, especially fuzzing a la [this paper](http://www.reverse-engineering.info/PE_Information/Crackers_Guide_To_Program_Flow.pdf)

Also, Peter Van Eeckhoutte covered what you're attempting to do in (in-memory fuzzing) in [this blogpost](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2010/10/20/in-memory-fuzzing/)

Both are outlined step by step

Comment: First paper doesn't even mention `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`. Additionally, `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` cannot be used to create a process snapshot that is easily useable for the purposes of execution control.

Comment: I said it would help, as in supplemental
also its not for execution control its to restore state:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/tlhelp32/nf-tlhelp32-createtoolhelp32snapshot
"th32ProcessID: The process identifier of the process to be included in the snapshot. This parameter can be zero to indicate the current process. This parameter is used when the TH32CS_SNAPHEAPLIST, TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, or TH32CS_SNAPALL value is specified. Otherwise, it is ignored and all processes are included in the snapshot."

Comment: one can use the Context struct for the values returned in this manner along with CreateThread, GetThreadContext and SetThreadContext
last, i mentioned an easier, already writ way via Corelan